# Route is not working in my CI live server

Tags: codeigniter, routes

This is mine route directory .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

the app is working only for home route i changed it from
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure rewrite_module is enabled on your server

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart your apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then add this to your config file under `sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/SITE_DIRECTORY>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally add `RewriteEngine on` to your `.htaccess`